# Array in Hexadecimal in Assembly x86 MASM

Tags: arrays, memory, assembly, x86, masm

If:
(I believe the registers are adjacent to one another...)

```
 A BYTE 0xB, 0d20, 0d10, 0d13, 0x0C
 B WORD 0d30, 0d40, 0d70, 0hB 
 D DWORD 0xB0, 0x200, 0x310, 0x400, 0x500, 0x600
```

Then:

- What is [A+2]? The answer is 0d20 or 0x15
- What is [B+2]? The answer is 40 or 0x28
- What is [D+4]? Not sure
- What is [D-10]? Not sure

I think those are the answers but I am not sure. Since a WORD is 1 BYTE, AND DWORD is 2 WORDS, then as a result when you are counting the array of [B+2] for example, you should be starting at 0d30, then 0d40 (count two WORD). And [A+2] is 0d20 because you are counting two bytes. What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thank you

**EDIT**

So is it because: Taking into account that the first value of A,B, and D are offsets x86 is little endian... A = 0d10, count 2 more from there B...bytes (in decimal) = 30,0,40,0,70,0,11,0 B is 0d40, count 2 more bytes from that D...bytes (in hex) = 0x200, 0,0,0,...0,2,0,0,...0x10,3,0,0,...0,4,0,0,...0,5,0,0,...0,6,‌​0,0 D is 0x200. Count 4 bytes from there. Count 10 bytes backwards from 0xb0. So wouldn't [D-10] be equal to 0x0C? Thank you

Also if I did [B-3], would it be 0d13? I was told it actually is between 0d10 and 0d13 such that it will be 0A0D and due to little endian will be 0D0A. Is that correct? Thank you!!
**EDIT**

Comment: The answers depend on operand sizes and whether your assembler uses byte offsets or typed indices.

Comment: The assembler is MASM. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what MASM uses, but the first answer is definitely wrong. Remember offsets start from zero. So that's `0d10`. `[B+2]` is correct for byte offsets. `[D+4]` is just `0x200` since 4 bytes is just the second dword. `[D-10]` is tricky, that will start at the `0d13` of `A` and through to `0d30` of `B`, giving you `0x001E0C13` (due to little endian).

Comment: Oh, now I got it, those "20 or 0x15" and "40 or 0x28" meant the same number, right? Then you converted 20 wrong, it's `0x14` (1*16 + 4 = 20). Anyway, learn ASAP to compile something + launch it in debugger, where you can use memory window to verify what bytes were produced, and the instructions view to see how what addresses were compiled into instructions for those +2.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get 0d13 of A and through to 0d30 of B @Jester? Thank you. Is it because since two WORD equal a DWORD, then each value in B will occupy two "slots" as you count back? And each value in A will occupy four "slots"? Thank you.

Comment: So is it because:
Taking into account that the first value of A,B, and D are offsets
x86 is little endian...
A = 0d10, count 2 more from there
B...bytes (in decimal) = 30,0,40,0,70,0,11,0
B is 0d40, count 2 more bytes from that
D...bytes (in hex) = 0x200, 0,0,0,...0,2,0,0,...0x10,3,0,0,...0,4,0,0,...0,5,0,0,...0,6,0,0
D is 0x200. Count 4 bytes from there.
Count 10 bytes backwards from 0xb0. So wouldn't [D-10] be equal to 0x0C? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WORD are 2 BYTEs. DWORD are two WORDs ("D" stands for "double"). QWORD is 4*WORD (Quad).

**Memory** is addressed in bytes, ie. content of memory can be viewed as (for three bytes with values: 0xB, 20, 10):

```
address | value
----------------
0000    | 0B
0001    | 14
0002    | 0A
```

WORD then occupies two bytes in memory, on x86 the least significant byte goes at lower address, most significant is at higher address.

So WORD 0x1234 is stored in memory at address 0xDEAD as:

```
address | value
----------------
DEAD    | 34
DEAE    | 12
```

Registers on x86 are special tiny bit of memory located directly on CPU itself, which is not addressable by the numerical addresses like above, but only by the instruction opcode containing the number of register (in source their are named `ax`, `bx`, ...).

That means you have no registers in your question, and it makes no sense to talk about registers in it.

In normal assembler [B+2] would be BYTE 40, (bytes at B are: 30, 0, 40, 0, 70, 0, 11, 0). In MASM it may be different, as it's trying to work with "variables" considering also their size, so [B+2] may be treated as WORD 70. I don't know for sure, and I don't want to know, MASM has too many quirks to be used logically, and you have to learn them. (just create short code with `B WORD 0, 1, 2, 3, 4` `MOV ax,[B+2]` and check the disassembly in debugger).

[A+2] is 10. You are missing the point that [A] is [A+0]. Like in C/C++ arrays, indexing goes from 0, not from 1.

Rest of answers can be easily figured out, if you draw the bytes on the paper (for example DWORD `0x310` compiles to `10 03 00 00` hexa bytes).

I wonder where you got 0x15 in first possible answer, as I don't see any value 21 in `A`.

---

edit due to new comments ... I will "compile" it for you, make sure you either understand every byte, or ask under answer which one is not clear.

```
; A BYTE 0xB, 0d20, 0d10, 0d13, 0x0C
A:
    0B 14 0A 0D 0C
; B WORD 0d30, 0d40, 0d70, 0hB 
B: ;▼     ▼     ▼     ▼
    1E 00 28 00 46 00 0B 00
; D DWORD 0xB0, 0x200, 0x310, 0x400, 0x500, 0x600 
D: ;▼           ▼           ▼           ▼           ▼           ▼
    B0 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 10 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 06 00 00
```

Notice how `A`, `B` and `D` are just labels marking some address in memory, that's how most Assemblers work with symbols. In MASM it's more tricky, as it tries to be "clever" and keeps not only the address around, but also it knows the `D` was defined as DWORD and not BYTE. That's not the case with different assemblers.

Now `[D+4]` in MASM is tricky, it will probably use the size knowledge to default to DWORD size of that expression (in other assemblers you should specify, like "DWORD PTR [D+4]", or it is deduced from target register size automatically, when possible). So [D+4] will fetch bytes `00 02 00 00` = DWORD `00000200`. (I just hope MASM doesn't recalculate also the +4 offset as +4th dword, ie +16 in bytes).

Now to your comments, I will torn them apart into tiny bits with mistakes, as while often it's easy to understand what you did mean, in Assembly once you start writing code, it's not enough to have good intention, you must be exact and accurate, CPU will not fill any gap, and do exactly what you wrote.

> Can you explain how did you get 0d13 of A and through to 0d30 of B @Jester?

Go to my "compiled" bytes, and D-1 (when offset are in bytes) means one byte back from `D:` address, ie. that `00` at the end of B line. Now for `D-10` count 10 bytes back from `D:` ... That will go to `0D` in `A` line, as 8 bytes are in `B` array, and remaining two are at end of `A` array.

Now if you read from that address 4 bytes: `0D 0C 1E 00` = DWORD `001E0C0D`. (Jester mixed up decimal `13` into `13h` by accident in his final "dword" value)

> each value in B will occupy two "slots" as you count back? And each value in A will occupy four "slots"?

It's other way around, two values in B will form 1 DWORD slot, and four values in A will form 1 DWORD. Just as "D" data of 6 DWORD can be treated also as 12 WORD values, or 24 BYTE values. For example `DWORD PTR [A+2]` is `1E0C0D0A`.

> first value of A,B, and D are offsets x86 is little endian

"value of A" is actually some memory address, I think I automatically don't mention "value" in such case, but "address", "pointer" or "label" (although "value of symbol A" is valid English sentence, and can be resolved after symbols have addresses assigned).

`OFFSET A` has particular special meaning in MASM, taking the byte offset of address `A` since the start of it's segment (in 32b mode this is usually the "address" for human, as segments start from 0 and memory is flat-mapped. In real mode segment part of address was important, as offset was only 16 bit (only 64k of memory addressable through offset only)).

In your case I would say "value **at** A", as "content of memory at address A". It's subtle, I know, but when everyone talks like this, it's clear.

> B is 0d40

`[B+2]` is `40`. `B+2` is some address+2. `B` is some address. It's the `[x]` brackets marking "value from memory at *x*".

Although in MASM it's a bit different, it will compile `mov eax,D` as `mov eax,DWORD PTR [D]` to mimic "variable" usage, but that's specific quirk of MASM. Avoid using that syntax, it hides memory usage from unfocused reader of source, use `mov eax,[D]` even in MASM (or get rid of MASM ideally).

> D...bytes (in hex) = 0x200, 0,0,0,...

`0x200` is not byte, hexa formatting has that neat feature, that two digits pair form single byte. So hexa `200` is 3 digits => one and half of byte.

Consider how those DWORD values were created from bytes.. in decimal formatting you would have to recalculate the whole value, so bytes 40,30,20,10 are 40 + 30*256 + 20*65536 + 10*16777216 = 169090600 -> the original values are not visible there. With hexa `28 1E 14 0A` you just reassemble them in correct order `0A141E28`.

> D is 0x200.

No, `D` is address. And even `[D]` is `0xB0`.

> Count 10 bytes backwards from 0xb0. So wouldn't [D-10] be equal to 0x0C?

`B0` is at D+0 address. You don't count it into those 10 bytes in [D-10], that `B0` is zero bytes beyond `D` (D+0). Look at my "compiled" memory and count bytes there to get comfortable with offsets.